# Slick- use foreignKey constraint and access referenced object directly as column

Tags: scala, foreign-key-relationship, slick, type-conversion

I have two models (say, **Supplier** and **Coffee**) and Coffee model has foreign key reference to Supplier model. During ddl, I want this relationship to exist in table creation. But I also want to be able to refer the Supplier object through Coffee object like `coffeeObj.supplier.name`. Below is my dummy code. I am using [MappedTable](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#mapped-tables), [foreignKey](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#constraints) and [TypeMapper](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#user-defined-functions-and-types).

```scala
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

object SlickTest {
  // Supplier
  case class Supplier(id: Option[Int], name: String)
  object Suppliers extends Table[Supplier]("supplier") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def * = id.? ~ name <> (Supplier, Supplier.unapply _)
    def findOneById(id: Int): Supplier = 
      this.map { e => e }.where(r => r.id === id).firstOption.get
  }

  // Implicit Conversion from Supplier to Int
  implicit val supTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[Supplier, Int](
    { s => s.id.get }, { id => Suppliers.findOneById(id) })

  // Coffee
  case class Coffee(name: Option[String], sup: Supplier, price: Double)
  object Coffees extends Table[Coffee]("coffee") {
    def name = column[String]("cof_name", O.PrimaryKey)
    def sup = column[Supplier]("supplier")
    def price = column[Double]("price")
    def * = name.? ~ sup ~ price <> (Coffee, Coffee.unapply _)

    def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", sup, Suppliers)(_.id)
  }
}
```

The code is failing at the last line for the definition of `supplier`. Could anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 8):

In Slick you don't map to case classes that reference other case classes. To resolve foreign keys you use queries instead, which you can put into methods for re-usability.

Also see my post at: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/esFb2DjoHVE/NtMj7BmpE94J

**EDIT:**
You can't follow a reference in coffeeObj and that is a good thing. Because that would require configuring a loading strategy like in ORMs, which would be more complicated and would make the execution behavior of your code less obvious.

Lazy loading would probably load the coffeeObj in the controller and the supplier in the view, which seems odd, right? You can do this:

**Remove** `.firstOption.get` from your `findOneById` method and then:

```scala
val supplierQuery = Query(Suppliers).findById(id)
val coffeeQuery = supplierQuery.join(Coffee).on(...).map(_._2)
// here is what you want, a supplier and the corresponding coffee:
val supplierWithCoffee = (supplierQuery.firstOption,coffeeQuery.f​irstOption)
```

Put the join into a function to save boiler plate.

Comment: So, there is no way to access `coffeeObj.supplier.name`?

Comment: You can't follow a reference in coffeeObj and that is a good thing. I extended the answer with more info on that.

Comment: Use `TableQuery[Suppliers]` instead of `Query(Suppliers)` in Slick 0.8

Comment: in Slick >= 2.0 or play-slick >= 0.8 (or 0.7?) that is :)